# How to compile ZipFile class (C#) in command line

Tags: c#, .net, zip

Before I start describing my problem I wanna say I did everything what I supposed to do in order to make ZipFile class functional. I mean, my target framework is .Net 4.5, I added references ( System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll and System.IO.Compression.dll ).

I can build the project within the Visual Studio without problem, no error. BUT when I try to compile the project using Command line that's when it gets interesting. I get everytime a error "error CS0103: the name ZipFile class does not exist in the current context".

The command for compiling in the CMD is: **csc /define:DEBUG /optimize /out:tbuild.exe *.cs**

Does anybody come across similar or even the same problem and knows solution for it, please?

Comment: Why do you need to build with the command line? If you need to "automate", you should be using MSBUILD to build from your solution or project.

Comment: I'm using from the beginning csc compiler and did not think of that, sorry for that, thank you though.

Comment: The MSBuild is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

First off, +1 on the msbuild suggestion, or you could look at something like [Fake](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExploringFAKEAnFBuildSystemForAllOfNET.aspx)

You specify the reference to System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll etc... in your visual studio project. Then you proceed to build your exe using only *.cs files. 
I think you should specify any references other than System.dll on the command line as well like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yabyz3h4.aspx)